# Need to remove the xml child by attribute value in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I want to remove the child tag from this xml . for example i want to remove this one

```
"<ExtraCategory diffgr:id="ExtraCategory1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <Barcode>5051694676090</Barcode>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <Value>High Quality</Value>
</ExtraCategory>"
```

Child. I am parsing the xml in this way.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($Xmlresult);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
unset($doc->xpath("ExtraCategory[@diffgr:id=$id]")[0]);
```

But failed to remove. I have done all the anwsers on stackoverflow but failed to get solution. Any help will be appreciated. my xml is following:

```
<DocumentElement
    xmlns="">
    <ExtraCategory diffgr:id="ExtraCategory1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <Barcode>5051694676090</Barcode>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <Value>High Quality</Value>
    </ExtraCategory>
    <ExtraCategory diffgr:id="ExtraCategory2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
        <Barcode>5051694676090</Barcode>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <Value>Stylish Appearance</Value>
    </ExtraCategory>
    <ExtraCategory diffgr:id="ExtraCategory3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
        <Barcode>5051694676090</Barcode>
        <CategoryID>3</CategoryID>
        <Value>In Fashion</Value>
    </ExtraCategory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just `unset()` an XML node, you need to remove the node from the DOM.  Something like...

```
   $Xmlresult = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocumentElement
    xmlns:diffgr="http://someURL" xmlns:msdata="http://someURL">
    <ExtraCategory diffgr:id="ExtraCategory1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <Barcode>5051694676090</Barcode>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <Value>High Quality</Value>
    </ExtraCategory>
    <ExtraCategory diffgr:id="ExtraCategory2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
        <Barcode>5051694676090</Barcode>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <Value>Stylish Appearance</Value>
    </ExtraCategory>
    <ExtraCategory diffgr:id="ExtraCategory3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
        <Barcode>5051694676090</Barcode>
        <CategoryID>3</CategoryID>
        <Value>In Fashion</Value>
    </ExtraCategory>
</DocumentElement>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($Xmlresult);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$id="ExtraCategory1";
$xpath->registerNamespace("diffgr", "http://someURL");
$removeNode = $xpath->query("//ExtraCategory[@diffgr:id=\"$id\"]")[0];
$removeNode->parentNode->removeChild($removeNode);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

The `registerNamespace` is needed to allow you to reference the namespace in the XPath expression, you will need to correct the namespace as this is just a dummy one I used to make it work.

The main bit is using `removeChild`, this is a bit of a convoluted statement, but it takes the node you want to remove, goes up to it's parent node and then removes the child node from it.

will give...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocumentElement xmlns:diffgr="http://someURL" xmlns:msdata="http://someURL">

    <ExtraCategory diffgr:id="ExtraCategory2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
        <Barcode>5051694676090</Barcode>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <Value>Stylish Appearance</Value>
    </ExtraCategory>
    <ExtraCategory diffgr:id="ExtraCategory3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
        <Barcode>5051694676090</Barcode>
        <CategoryID>3</CategoryID>
        <Value>In Fashion</Value>
    </ExtraCategory>
</DocumentElement>
```

(Note I've added the declaration of the namespaces, you will probably have your own definitions, but I needed to add something.)